# passing form values from fancy box popup to main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am currently working on a web app using python and Django, and i have a screen with a popup using the fancybox jquery plugin.

When the link is clicked it opens a url on my server which is basically a form.

What i am trying to achieve is the ability to pass the values of the form inputs to my main page once the popup is closed.

I have a funny feeling that is isnt going to be possible and i might be better off using hidden divs (which hide so on command) rather than a popup.

my test page:

```
<div class='link'>
    <a class='fancy' href='create/' > click me </a>
</div
```

the javascript atm:

```
$(function(){
  $('.fancy').fancybox(
   {
     type:'ajax',
     afterClose: function(){
        alert('done!');
     }
   }
});
```

The main idea is the popup has a form which has values which will be added to the Django database, but there is also a table on the main window which also displays these.
I wanted to make the main window to be the one which creates the object, saves it and then loads it into the form ( this is taken care of from a API call which i use ajax)

any help at all would be great

Answer (score 0):

Following is a very simplistic pub/sub that creates a stored object and updates object and page elements using `change` event of form inputs

Html:

```
<!-- table, match "data-bind" to form input name -->
<td data-bind="fname" class="subscriber">Foo</td>
<td data-bind="lname"  class="subscriber">Bar</td>
<!-- form -->
<input type="text" name="fname" class="data_source" />
```

JS:

```
/* declare empty object */
var storedData = {};

var $subscribers=$('.subscriber');
/* this event triggered when input changes*/
$(document).on('upDataData', function( event, key, value){
    storedData[key]=value;
    $subscribers.filter( '[data-bind="'+key+'"]').text( value );
});


/* change handler for form inputs*/
$(document).on('change', 'form input.data_source', inputChange);

function inputChange(){       
    $(document).trigger('upDataData',[ this.name, this.value]);
}
/* populate storedData from table elements when page loads*/
function createInitialData(){
    $subscribers.each(function(){
        storedData[ $(this).data('bind')]= $(this).text();
    });
}

 createInitialData()
```

Then in your fancybox code send object to server and parse values into form with server code:

```
$('.fancy').fancybox({
     type:'ajax',
     /* same as "options" for "$.ajax"*/
     ajax: { data : storedData},
     afterClose: function(){
        alert('done!');
     }       
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xg9ML/2/